# Same KafkaTemplate with different configuration for transactional and non-transactional Kafka producers

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Through the allowNonTransactional property, it's possible to use the same KafkaTemplate to create transactional and non-transactional producers. Both producer kinds will use the same configuration coming from the KafkaProducerFactory.

In some specific cases, it may be required to use a different configuration for these 2 kinds of producers.

The following example shows a concrete use case

- KafkaTemplate - non-transactional producer -> linger.ms=100
- KafkaTemplate - transactional producer -> linger.ms=2000

Issue could be solved by having 2 factories and/or 2 templates but to avoid boiler plate code and complexity, the idea would be to keep the same template.

Is there currently a way to support this use case?

If not, it would be great to have a support for it. Through a tx prefix, it may be possible to have an override of default configuration entries for transactional producers.

- KafkaTemplate - non-transactional producer -> linger.ms=100
- KafkaTemplate - transactional producer -> tx.linger.ms=2000
  These properties may be given using spring.kafka.producer.properties.*

Any feedback on that questions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a constructor that allows overriding the producer factory configuration.

```java
    /**
     * Create an instance using the supplied producer factory and autoFlush setting.
     * <p>
     * Set autoFlush to {@code true} if you have configured the producer's
     * {@code linger.ms} to a non-default value and wish send operations on this template
     * to occur immediately, regardless of that setting, or if you wish to block until the
     * broker has acknowledged receipt according to the producer's {@code acks} property.
     * If the configOverrides is not null or empty, a new
     * {@link ProducerFactory} will be created using
     * {@link org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory#copyWithConfigurationOverride(java.util.Map)}
     * The factory shall apply the overrides after the supplied factory's properties.
     * The {@link org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerPostProcessor}s from the
     * original factory are copied over to keep instrumentation alive.
     * Registered {@link org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory.Listener}s are
     * also added to the new factory. If the factory implementation does not support
     * the copy operation, a generic copy of the ProducerFactory is created which will
     * be of type
     * DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.
     * @param producerFactory the producer factory.
     * @param autoFlush true to flush after each send.
     * @param configOverrides producer configuration properties to override.
     * @since 2.5
     * @see Producer#flush()
     */
    public KafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<K, V> producerFactory, boolean autoFlush,
            @Nullable Map<String, Object> configOverrides) {
```

Comment: This won't solve the issue as the use case is to use 1 factory and 1 template for both transactional and non-transactional producer WITH a different config for transactional and non-transactional producers. Would be great if the factory (the default one) may handle this allowing overrides of configuration entries for transactional producers. The alternative would be to use one factory with 2 templates by using the constructor as suggested.

Comment: It's already complicated enough for users to understand; I personally don't think the added complexity to support this use case is worth it; using 2 templates is simple enough. But feel free to open a new feature request, and contributions are welcome.

Comment: Comment does not support enough characters. See my answer for a possible support. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70699004/5065190

Answer (score 0):

Agree with you, this is already complicated enough for most use cases.

In our use case, some layers have been built on top of the KafkaTemplate which is hidden and can be considered as internal from a user point of view.
A solution may be to check if we are in a transaction when performing an operation.
Which is something already given by KafkaTemplate#inTransaction

To avoid this, a slight internal rework may be done in the DefaultProducerFactory as follow

```
// private -> protected
// new rawConfigs parameters
protected CloseSafeProducer<K, V> doCreateTxProducer(String prefix, String suffix,
        BiPredicate<CloseSafeProducer<K, V>, Duration> remover, Map<String, Object> rawConfigs) {
    // same as now
}
```

Doing this will give a way to customize the configuration if needed.

Same may also be done for the createKafkaProducer (already protected, just a new param) method for consistency reasons.

If you agree, I would be more than happy to open a feature request and drop a PR for it. If not, we can consider the question as answered

Thanks again for your very quick reply.

Comment: Sure, feel free to submit a PR for the issue and we can discuss further there.

Comment: issue created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2070 and PR submitted https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2075

Comment: @GaryRussell, did you get a change to check the PR? Any feedbacks are welcome. The issue is quite important for my company and I and it would be great to have it in one of the next releases of Spring Kafka.

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I will take a look today.